# I am requesting access token from gfycat api. What am I doing wrong in the below screenshot?

Tags: api, postman, gfycat

I am requesting access token from **Gfycat API**.

I have entered the details in Postman as mentioned below, i.e. Client secret, still getting BAD Request error.

Please help me identifying what I am doing wrong.

For details, please see the below screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v62AA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues in the screenshot:

1. There's `client_id` twice, instead of one `client_id` and one `client_secret`
2. You put the key/values in Postman's Header tab instead of the Params tab.

It's a straightforward request, you can even get an auth token from your browser with a simple URL (no header or body)
`https://api.gfycat.com/v1/oauth/token?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials`